# Following MVVM Example - Droptargets get disabled after docking in some direction

Tags: avalondock

I am following an Avalondock-example on github:

https://github.com/8/AvalonDockMVVM

It works well, but I want the possibility to dock in more than one direction. Can anyone explain how this can be done?

I'll add a couple of images as an example of what I mean:

[image: Sample Image]

What I want is to let the user place windows both in the left/right-direction and in the up/down-direction. Can anybody please point me in the right direction? Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the **AllowMixedOrientation** Property ?

```xml
<xcad:DockingManager 
   Grid.Row="1“ 
   MaxHeight="425" 
   AllowMixedOrientation="True" 
   BorderBrush="Black" 
   BorderThickness="1">
<!--your Code-->
</xcad:DockingManager
```

Found here: [Wpf Toolkit on Codeplex](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock&referringTitle=Home)